# About structure of the set of perfect matchings of $K_{n,n}$

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory, perfect-matchings

1. Are there any special properties known about the set of perfect matchings of $K_{n,n}$? Like any global structure of this set? Some natural way to partition it? Like is there some algebraic structure on this set? Some group that is known to may be act nicely on this set? (this might be a broad question, so feel free to just link to something you know that goes this way!)
2. Given a perfect matching of $K_{n,n}$ is there a systematic way to generate other perfect matchings (disjoint) from it?
3. How large a set of mutually disjoint perfect matchings of $K_{n,n}$ can be obtained ? And how to obtain such a set?

---

- That count of $\prod_{i=0}^{d-1} (n-i)!$ is what I think is the number of ways one can pick $d$ mutually disjoint perfect matchings of $K_{n,n}$ (the $k^{th}$ factor above corresponds to the number of ways the $k^{th}$ perfect matching can be chosen having made the previous choices)
- $d-1 = n$ is the largest $d$ for which the factor stops being defined.
  So naively I feel $d = n +1$ is the largest $d$ for which one can find $d$ mutually disjoint perfect matchings. Though I don't know if this d is the largest possible.  (by cyclic permutations I seem to be able to generate atmost only $n$ mutually disjoint perfect matchings)
- I saw some related papers like, http://www.tau.ac.il/~nogaa/PDFS/mincg3.pdf and http://math.cmu.edu/~af1p/Texfiles/matchplusbip.pdf
- A related MO discussion, [Postnikov's approach to perfect matchings of graphs](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/169053/postnikovs-approach-to-perfect-matchings-of-graphs)
- Feel free to may be generalize any of the above questions to the case of more general bipartite graphs or general graphs!

Comment: 2. Apply a derangement (fixed point free permutation) of the right hand vertices.  3. You can find $n$ disjoint perfect matchings by repeatedly applying Hall's Theorem. This is obviously best possible.

Comment: You are asking about Latin rectangles. For $d=2$ see the derangement numbers. After that enumeration gets tougher; your formula is completely wrong. As Tony points out, $d=n$ is the greatest possible, and that's a Latin square.  Nobody knows how many Latin squares there are for arbitrary $n$ either.

Comment: @BrendanMcKay I am not getting you. What is the analogy to derangement problem? An identity permutation of n-elements is clearly a valid perfect matching of $K_{n,n}$ but that is not a derangement.

Comment: [My formula counts this simple thing : Let us build a set of mutually disjoint perfect matchings. There are n! ways of choosing the first perfect matching. For the second perfect matching the first vertex on the left can go anywhere except wherever it went in the first perfect matching and hence it has $(n-1)$ choices. The second vertex can go anywhere except where the first vertex went in the 2nd PM and where it itself went in the first PM. Hence it has (n-2) choices and so on. So the 2nd PM can be chosen in $(n-1)!$ ways. and now you go on till adding $d-$perfect matchings.

Comment: I guess I should have a product over $(n-i)!$ - changed that.

Comment: Isn't a perfect matching of $K_{n,n}$ just a permutation, or am I missing something? Two permutations are "non-intersecting" if they do not agree on any entry, in which case the perfect matchings are disjoint. So write down each permutation corresponding to a perfect matching in the rows of an array and you build a Latin rectangle.

Comment: ^Yes. Thats how I see it.

Comment: @GordonRoyle True. So isn't my formula counting it right? (and can you may be give a proof by $d=n$ is the largest possible, though I was feeling that $d=n+1$ is somehow also allowed)

Comment: There are only $n^2$ edges, so once you've built $n$ disjoint perfect matchings, you've run out of edges. Any Latin square will give you a set of $n$ perfect matchings, simply reading it row-by-row as permutations in image form.

Comment: So is there a Latin square way of thinking of the adjacency matrix of the graph obtained after putting in $d$ disjoint perfect matchings?

Comment: Yes, it is Latin rectangle: $d$ rows and $n$ columns, with each row containing a permutation and no column having anything twice.  The column numbers correspond to the vertices on one side of $K_{n,n}$, the row numbers correspond to which matching it is, and the entry values correspond to the vertices on the other side of $K_{n,n}$.

Comment: No. I mean - the adjacency matrix of $K_{n,n}$ (after putting in $d$ perfect matchings) is a $2n \times 2n$ matrix. Can this be seen as somehow being equal or built out of Latin rectangles? Is something known about determinants of Latin rectangles? (especially after say I flip a few of the $1$s in the adjacency matrix to $-1$s maintaining the symmetry)

Comment: Your formula is incorrect except for $d=1$ because the number of choices for each entry depends on the number of possibilities excluded so far by this matching as well as the number excluded by the previous matchings.  Those two types of exclusion overlap in general, so the number of exclusions in total is not determined precisely; it varies with the history.

Comment: When I am adding in the $i$th edge of the $k+1$-th perfect matching I can't map it to any of the $k$ places $i$ has gone to in the previous $k$ rounds and everywhere the first $(i-1)$ vertices have gone to till now in this round. So a total of $k+i-1$ options are ruled out for it. So it has $n-k-i+1$ options left. So the total number of options is $\prod_{k=1}^{k=d} \prod_{i=1}^{i=n} (n-k-i+1)$. Is this wrong?

Comment: Yes, it is wrong.  Some of the possibilities excluded by the previous rounds will also be excluded by the previous choices in this round. You are counting those possibilities twice.

Comment: The matching polytope of $K_{n,n}$ leads to a "global structure" on the set of all matchings, e.g., those sets of matchings that form a face.

Comment: So there is no way to count the number of possible ways one can pick d mutually disjoint perfect matchings of $K_{n,n}$?

Comment: A good survey is at http://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/v17i1a1

Comment: Thanks a lot for so much effort! I had never heard of latin rectangles before and I had no clue that this almost trivial sounding question leads to quite deep things! I wonder, is anything known about determinants of adjacency matrices of such {n,n}-bipartite graphs whose edge set has a decomposition into d mutually disjoint perfect matchings? (basically if latin square thinking leads to something here!) (and if i flip a few of the 1s to -1s in this adjacency matrix maintaining symmetry)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe I'll summarise everything from the comments as an answer.

Firstly, a perfect matching $M$ of $K_{n,n}$ can be identified with a permutation of the set $[n] = \{1,\ldots,n\}$ simply by numbering each side of the bipartition with $[n]$ and letting $\sigma$ be such that $(i,\sigma(i))$ is an edge of $M$.

Therefore $K_{n,n}$ has exactly $n!$ perfect matchings. It is not immediately clear to me as to whether there is anything gained by thinking of perfect matchings as opposed to just thinking of permutations.

Now move on to disjoint perfect matchings. Two perfect matchings, viewed as permutations $\sigma$, $\tau$ will be disjoint if and only if $\sigma^{-1} \tau$ has no fixed points and therefore is a derangement. If we simply label things so that $\sigma$ is the identity, then  $\tau$ will be disjoint from it if and only if it *itself* is a derangement. Luckily we know the number of derangements, as it is the closest integer to $n!/e$, so we can count the number of disjoint pairs of perfect matchings.

Now we want to add a third perfect matching, disjoint from both. We can write down everything so far in an array, where each row is a permutation written in image format (in other words, just a list $\sigma(1)$, $\sigma(2)$, $\sigma(3)$, etc). So the first row can be the identity, just $1$, $2$, $3$, $\ldots$, $n$ and then the second row will be a derangement, and thus no column of the $2 \times n$ array we have constructed will have a repeated symbol. Adding a third perfect matching disjoint from the two first is precisely equivalent to adding another row to the array such that none of the columns of this $3 \times n$ array have repeated symbols.

This can be continued, until after $d$ pairwise disjoint perfect matchings, we have built a $d \times n$ *Latin Rectangle*. Simple counting shows that $d \leq n$ because by the time the $n \times n$ Latin square has been constructed every edge lies in a unique perfect matching already accounted for, so there are no more edges.

Counting Latin squares is a well-known very difficult problem, and there is no simple counting technique or formula that can accomplish this.